# a one minute's talk

Tags: british-english, possessives

I know that the right way to say it is:

> a one-minute talk
>
> one minute's talk

However, I come across these examples:

> 1. Batt's track, “**A One Minute's** Silence”, consists of the absence of any digital signal, whereas Cage's 4'33”
> 2. 'One monstrous fact can be ascertained here in the course of **a one-minute's** conversation with any official at the Emigrants' depot'
> 3. Manchester United players give **a one minute's** applause in memory of …
> 4. This gives **a one minute's** fall at the lunar orbit corresponding to 60 earth radii as the lunar distance of c(60)(p/ (39,343)2) 1⁄4 15.072 Paris feet.

**Are all those typos or not?**

Comment: Sources for your quotes? If intended to be possessive uses, I think they are not standard at best (AmE). I would use "one minute" instead. But artistic license...

Comment: Them all look okay to me. :)

Comment: Also, *"So, you got yourself a one trick pony?"*

Comment: Oh, to answer your question: No, they probably aren't typos. That is, what was written was probably what was intended to be written.

Comment: What's the purpose of this "a"? Is there a difference between "one minute's talk" and "a one minute's talk"?

Comment: Yes, there is a difference between "one minute's talk" and "a one minute's talk". Consider: *"This morning, I took a five minute walk in the part"*, which is acceptable, and the unacceptable *"This morning, I took five minute walk in the part"*. For we're dealing with a "five minute" walk in the part, and I took one of them this morning.

Comment: You are not being attentive enough. Take heed. We are not talking about "a one-minute talk", we are talking about "a one minute's talk".

Comment: I'm plenty attentive enough. That's a 2nd issue, which would probably take up a much bigger hunk of time to explain. Someone might actually address that 2nd issue in an answer post. But what could help is if you now went and edited your question post so that the two issues can be seen as separate issues. Note your original comparison: "**a** one-minute talk" vs "one **minute's** talk". -- There's two issues involved. I had chosen to address the easier one in my comments.

Comment: My original comparison is not the issue. It's an example of the standard usage. There is only one issue here "a one minute's talk".

Comment: Er, . . . whatever.

Comment: Great, now I’m going to have [4′33″](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTEFKFiXSx4) stuck in my head all day.

Comment: They're all standard.  It has nothing to do with artistic license.  Although genitive NPs typically fill the determiner slot (and would therefore not co-occur with *a*) certain genitive NPs can also appear attributively (e.g. "He lives in **an old people's home**").  See *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, p.470, under "Measure genitives", where you can find examples like "a second [**one hour's** delay]".

Comment: @snailboat It may be legal but still I don't think it is a common usage. In the case of "an old people's home", *old-people's* describes a type of home, wheras *a one-minute's* talk does not describe a type of of talk. Could you say "I took a one hour's nap."? Sorry I don't think so.

Comment: @user3169 As an aside, you cannot hyphenate *old people's* in *an old people's home*, nor can you hyphenate *one minute's* in *a one minute's talk*.

Comment: See also Quirk et al's *Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* p.1333: "a ten days' absence"

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Consider it 4'33" of time you get to ignore the nonsense around you which you would otherwise have to listen to.

Comment: @snailboat Sorry that was my typo. I kept hitting on the hyphen in the question.

Answer (score 1):

No, they're British. I don't think most Americans would bother with the possessive when the phrase works fine without it.  Two-minute warning. A moment of silence. A ten-second pause.

Answer (score -1):

> *A one-minute talk*

is quite similar to -

> *A 24-year-old girl*

Now, `A one minute's (something)`

As we understand that here, the indefinite article is used for *something* (As in *he's a good boy*). In other words, the indefinite article is required especially when the coming *noun* is countable (here, 'boy').

**Adding apostrophe** shows the [possession](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/apostro.asp). As the example on that page is *A woman's hat*. Woman is a noun here that holds the possession of *hat*.

One of the examples you quoted is ...

> *Manchester United players give **a one minute's applause** in memory of...*

***One minute* is a noun that holds the possession of *applause***. The definite article makes sense.

I don't see any necessity to put *hyphen* in your *second* sentence.

Answer (score -1):

"A one minute talk" is a different scenario from "a one minute's talk".

"A one minute's talk" is wrong.

In English, most singular nouns need a *determiner* of some kind.  Usually these are the articles: "a book", "the book".  Sometimes they're demonstrative adjectives: "this book", "that book".

The cardinal number "one" can also be used as a determiner: "one book".

We can also use possessives as determiners: "Bob's book".

Thus, all of the following are correct:

- "I bought *a* book."
- "I bought *the* book."
- "I bought *this* book."
- "I bought *that* book."
- "I bought *one* book."
- "I bought *Bob's* book."

However, each noun can only have *one determiner at a time*.  I wouldn't be able to say "I bought *a one* book."  "A" and "one" are both determiners, and are both referring to "book".  You can only have one determiner per noun.

In the phrase "A one minute's talk", "one" acts as the determiner for "minute", and "one minute's" (as a possessive) acts as the determiner for "talk".  The "a" is redundant.  Thus, you want "one minute's talk".

By comparison: "A one-minute talk" is right.

I can take the phrase "one minute", and treat it as one big adjective.  (I would usually indicate this by connecting them with a hyphen - "one-minute".)  Thus, I could say:

- "a talk"
- "a *boring* talk"
- "a *one-minute* talk"
- "a *longer-than-necessary* talk"

All of these are correct, because "a" is the determiner for "talk", and "boring", "one-minute", and "longer-than-necessary" are all behaving as adjectives modifying "talk".